# Keep pagination work truly after inserting a new row to datagrid easy-ui

Tags: jquery, pagination, jquery-easyui

I have an easyui html table, which has a pagination. The default page number is one and number of rows displayed in first page is ten.
There is a method which insert a new row from database to index 0 of html table whenever a new row is added to table in database.
What I want is to keep number of rows ten or whatever selected in pagination bar. but by inserting a new row it goes eleven, twelve etc. how can I delete rows from the button of table as much as rows inserted at top and again insert the deleted rows at top of the previous page(page number 2) and again delete rows from the button of second page and insert at top of third page and etc.
In fact I want to keep pagination work truly even after inserting new rows. the problem is when inserting I don't load easy-ui datagrid again and so no page and rows parameter is sent to Controller in server to check the pagination. so above solution is something arrived to my mind but I don't know how can I implement it.

```
  $('#tt').datagrid('insertRow',
                                {
                                    index: 0,
                                    row:
                                    {
                                       name : message.name
                                       age : message.age
                                    },

                                }
                    );
```

Comment: what version of your jquery-easyui?

Comment: jQuery EasyUI 1.5.1.x @HilariusL.Doren